# how to display different user's wordpress post on my site

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to know how can I display the blog/post of other author on my site http://www.gymup.com? My site  don't have plugged in/ installed wordpress (and don't want to actually). Suppose One of my trainer on www.gymup.com having a blog on wordpress and he ask me to show his blog/post on their profile section. So I need to know is there wordpress API to full fill this requirements? Please suggest.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using their RSS feed?

Comment: thanks @njk we got the answer at same time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! I got the answer. We can get the RSS of all blog by putting /feed in the URL suppose my wordpress blog URL is http://avmishra.wordpress.com so we can get the RSS by http://avmishra.wordpress.com/feed and there are allot of library which can read the RSS and covert that in array.

Thanks.